# Proving Integral representation of $\zeta(n)$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Currently studying analytic number theory and was baffled by the following integral representation of $\zeta(n)$

$$\zeta(n) = \dfrac{2}{1 - 2^{1 - n}}\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi n}{2}\right)\int_0^\infty \dfrac{x^{-2n}}{\pi x}(1 - \pi x^2\csc[\pi x^2])dx$$

However there's no proof for this provided in the text. I am struggling on proving the same.

Any help or hints would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: A [nice paper](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_13/papers/david.pdf) summarizing the first 3 chapters of the book by H. Edwards on $\zeta$ function. Maybe you could find the answer in the following chapters of this book...